# I am trying to access sharepoint via C# code and i am getting UNAUTHORIZED access error but I can log web sharepoint without any issues

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am working on C#.net application that will interact with Sharepoint 2013 using the client object model approach to download and upload files. When I use my credentials to run the C#.net application it gives me below error.

- $exception  {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}    System.Net.WebException

But if I use same credentials to log in via Web Sharepoint it works fine. I don't understand what I need to plug into my code in order to access SharePoint to download/upload files.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
   public void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SharePoint Online site URL:");

        try
        {
            using (var context = new ClientContext(webSPOUrl))
            {
                Web web = context.Web;
                context.Load(web, website => website.Title);
                context.Load(web.Webs);

                CredentialCache cc = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
                cc.Add(new Uri(webSPOUrl), "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
                context.Credentials = cc;
                context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

                context.Load(web.Lists,
                    lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                        list => list.Id));


                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                foreach (List list in web.Lists)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("List title is: " + list.Title);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error is: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code snippet you provided, it seems you are trying to connect to *SharePoint Online* (O365). The network credentials object you use in your code is for connecting to traditional 'on premise' SharePoint installs. You should be using [SharePointOnlineCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj164693(v%3Doffice.15)) instead.

```
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,password);
context.Load(...);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, everyone, who have provided the solutions. Below is the working code:

```
public static void Uploadfiles(string SiteUrl, string DocLibrary, string ClientSubFolder, string FileName)
        {

            string webSPOUrl = "https://testdev.sharepoint.com/sites/test";
            Console.WriteLine("User Name:");
            string userName = "<your username >@testdev.onmicrosoft.com";
            Console.WriteLine("Password:");
            string librayName = "Documents";


                try
                {
                    using (var context = new SP.ClientContext(webSPOUrl))
                    {
                        // Sharepoint Online Authentication
                        context.Credentials = new SP.SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
                        SP.Web web = context.Web;

                        SP.FileCreationInformation newFile = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
                        byte[] FileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
                        newFile.ContentStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(FileContent);
                        newFile.Url = Path.GetFileName(FileName);
                        SP.List DocumentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocLibrary);

                        SP.Folder Clientfolder = DocumentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.Add(ClientSubFolder);

                        Clientfolder.Update();
                        SP.File uploadFile = Clientfolder.Files.Add(newFile);

                        context.Load(DocumentLibrary);
                        context.Load(uploadFile);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("The File has been uploaded" + Environment.NewLine + "FileUrl -->" + SiteUrl + "/" + DocLibrary + "/" + ClientSubFolder + "/" + Path.GetFileName(FileName));
                     } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide a user name, password and domain, this code worked for me:

```
var clientContext = new ClientContext(new Uri(someUrl))
{
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName","Password", "DomainName")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access SharePoint 2013 on-premise in client side, you can modify the code as below.

```
public void test()
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext(webSPOUrl))
        {
            context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web, website => website.Title);
            context.Load(web.Webs);
            context.Load(web.Lists,
                lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title,
                    list => list.Id));

            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            foreach (List list in web.Lists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List title is: " + list.Title);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error is: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```